# Access rawValue of enum in array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, enums, max, member

I'm trying to use `maxElement` to work with enums in an array, accessed by .rawValue as shown in the example below:

```
var planets: [Planets] = [.Mars, .Earth, .Jupiter]
maxElement(planets.rawValue)
```

I could just use other methods to get the max rawValue but it would be so nice and easy if it could be used this way, but is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way to that.

```
let maxPlanet = Planets(rawValue: maxElement(planets.map({$0.rawValue})))!
```

You have to:

1. make an array of `rawValue`s
2. get `maxElement` from that.
3. convert back to enum using `Planets(rawValue:)`

Answer (score 2):

Conform to `Comparable` protocol to use `maxElement` with your enum.

```
enum Planets: Int, Comparable {
    case Earth, Mars, Jupiter
}

func <(lhs: Planets, rhs: Planets) -> Bool {
    return lhs.rawValue < rhs.rawValue
}
```

Then

```
let planets: [Planets] = [.Mars, .Jupiter, .Earth]
let maxPlanet = maxElement(planets) // .Jupiter
```

Comment: Thanks, I've thought of looking up `Comparable` but that'd mean I have to edit all my enums. It works really great though!